# PostgreSQL объединение таблиц

Tags: postgresql

делаю запрос на получение имени продуктов, имени типов продуктов
всё получается

```
 select p.name, t.name from product as p inner join type as t on p.type_id = t.id;
```

но почему нельзя объедение две разные таблицы
в этом случае

```
select t.name, p.type_id, count(id) from product as p
group by p.type_id
having count(id) < 10
inner join type as t on t.id = p.type_id;
```

я же вывожу тип p.type_id   почему я не могу сразу же вывести по id  назавния типов они же совпадают?

Comment: Добавьте в группировку недостающее поле и подымите джойн выше неё, так никто не пишет

Answer (score 0):

Работающий запрос:

```
SELECT max(t.name), p.type_id, count(p.id)
FROM product p
  JOIN type t ON p.type_id = t.id
GROUP BY p.type_id
HAVING count(p.id) < 10;
```

Проблемы с текущим запросом из оригинального вопроса:

- согласно синтаксису SQL, `join` должно быть частью выражения `from`. `inner join` после `group by` не допускается
- в `count(id)` (как в `select`-части запроса, так и в `having`) непонятно, какая таблица имеется в виду, `product` или `type`.
- поскольку группировка сделана по полю `p.type_id`, поле `t.name` в `select` части запроса может относиться к нескольким записям, что также не допускается.

Comment: select t.name, p.type_id, count(id) from product as p
inner join type as t on t.id = p.type_id
group by p.type_id
having count(id) < 10;  так тоже не работает

Comment: Если запрос **из ответа** не работает, пишите пожалуйста сообщение об ошибке полностью.